# delete files in a sequence and count in shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

In a specific Unix directory on a server. I would like to list down files and delete them in a sequence one by one.
Below program is showing errors in `for` loop. Can anybody help to make it work?

```
#!/bin/sh
address=/apps/applications/jboss-as/servers/scripts/
files=$(ls $address)
echo Below files will be deleted-
echo $files

k=0
for i in "$files" do {
 rm $i       
 k++
}
done

echo ${k} files are deleted.
```

Comment: Is the error `$ k++ -bash: k++ : command not found` ? `k++` is an arithmetic expression and should be enclosed in double-parenthesis (i.e. `((k++))`)

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Do not do `files=$(ls $address)`, instead make `files="$address/*"`

Comment: Please paste the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the script, but as others pointed out, you may want to use something other than the `ls`, but I left it in.  There were other syntax errors as well.  Here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

address=/apps/applications/jboss-as/servers/scripts/
files=("$address"/*)

echo Below files will be deleted-
echo "${files[@]}"

k=0
for i in "${files[@]}" ; do
 echo "removing $i ..."
 rm "$i"
 ((k++))
done

echo ${k} files are deleted.
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Since you're still having trouble, you might add `declare -a files` just above the `files=( "$address"/* )`.  It *might* fix the problem for you (but, the script runs fine without it here), and it doesn't hurt anything when I run the script here with it.  So, either way ...

Comment: by some way "${files[@]}" doesn't iterate the array :(

Comment: o/p- removing hello.sh
hello.txt
jboss.txt
logs.txt
server.log

Comment: Last value of k is always 1

Comment: @UmeshPatil I've reverified it here and it works fine including the count and one message per file.  You may want to comment out the `rm` until you get the right effect.  It's one of the reasons I added the `echo`.  If you've cut-n-pasted correctly, there should be no problem.  You can try running it via `sh -x` to help debug.

Answer (score -1):

The first question is, what kind of error do you got?
Try this:

```
for file in $(ls ${files}/*); do
   ...
done
```

Best regards
Robert

Comment: -1. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29. Also please do not ask questions in answers, that's what the comment sections are for.

Comment: I asked in the answer, because i can't write a comment. Thanks for the link. I will study this.

Comment: arco444: Could you explain me, why I earned -1 reputation from you? If the author writes this variable in quotes in the loop, it's still not ok? Is it because, that in directory could have a whitspace?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10472484)

Comment: @Mad Physicist: Thanks, I learned, that it's only possible to ask for clarification in comment. Except for my question, I think I provided an answer. Maybe my answer should be more detailed.